# Real analysis: continuously differentiable and Lipschitz implies bounded derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Claim:

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $M$-th continuously differentiable ($f\in C^M$) for some $M\geq 2$ and $f$ is Lipschitz continuos on $\mathbb{R}$, then all the derivatives $f'$, $f''$, ... $f^{(M-1)}$ are bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this claim true? If not, are there any good counter-examples?

Comment: You mean $f$ is Lip-continuous or $f^{(M)}$?

Comment: only $f$ is Lipschitz continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

Pick a continuous positive function $g(x)$ which is unbounded, but still
$$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}g(t) \mathrm dt < \infty$$
Such an example may be $g(x)=x^2 \exp (-x^8 \sin^2 x)$

Then integrate it twice to get a function $f$ with the property that $f''=g$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. $f$ is twice continuously differentiable.

Now, $f'$ is bounded, so $f$ is Lipschitz. However, $f''$ is not bounded.

Comment: what about if I weaken it to $f'$, $f''$, $f^{(M-1)}$ are bounded? Sorry I forgot to mention this. I changed my question^

Comment: What's the purpose to put $\sin^{2}x$?

Comment: Nope. All you can say is that $f'$ is bounded. The example I showed you is infinitely diefferentiable, and only $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: I think you mean to have $g(t)$ in the integral, not $f(t).$

Comment: @user284331. If  $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x=\pi n$ then $-x^8\sin^2x=0$ so $g(x)=x^2=\pi^2n^2$. So $g$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Take as a counterexample the function

$$F(x)=\int_0^x\sin{(t^2)}dt$$

This function is Lipschitz and three times continuously differentiable but $F''$ is not bounded.